# ¿como puedo colocar lo de la "listasaludo" en un archivo de texto y que me escoja solo un saludo en python?

Tags: python

listasaludo = ["hola","hola que tal","buenos dias","que tal","que fue","que trip", "holis"]

Answer (score 1):

Si lo tienes en un archivo de texto (.txt), puedes hacer lo siguiente (Asumiendo que tienes cada saludo en una línea diferente!):

```
import random

saludo_elegido = "Hola" # Defino saludo_elegido por si falla al abrir el archivo
with open('listasaludo.txt', 'r') as file: # Abre el archivo en modo lectura
    saludos = file.read().splitlines() # Leo todo el archivo y lo asigno a saludos
    # usando splitlines(), que genera una lista con un elemento por cada línea
# Al estar abierto con el with no hace falta cerrarlo luego!
    saludo_elegido = random.choice(saludos) # Random.choice elige un elemento al azar de la lista
# Si ha fallado al abrir el archivo, al menos tendremos "Hola" como resultado
print(saludo_elegido)
```

Comment: Creo que la asignación y el `print` hay que indentarlos dentro del `with`, para que sólo se ejecuten si se pudo leer el archivo. Tal como está, si el `open` falla, `saludos` queda indefinida y se genera una excepción.

Comment: Efectivamente, aunque dado el caso supongo que sería mejor tener definida la variable con un valor por defecto. Muy buen visto

Comment: muchas gracias!! me ayudo bastante la información brindada, pude lograr el objetivo

Comment: La mejor manera de agradecer es marcar como respuesta. Además así otros usuarios con el mismo problema verán la solución también!